# How to disable the special character menu for haxe game

Tags: macos, haxe, openfl, haxeflixel

I'm working on a game written using haxeflixel and, on mac, whenever you hold down certain keys (A, for instance) a menu pops up at the top of the game window.

[image: Mac special character menu]

Is there any way to disable this menu inside my application only?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this OpenFL issue](https://github.com/openfl/openfl/issues/1146#issuecomment-221612058), OpenFL Next doesn't have this problem. There's two ways to enable Next:

- Add `-Dnext` when compiling on the command line.
- Add `<set name="next" />` to your `Project.xml`. Note that this line has to come before `<haxelib name="flixel" />`.